# Argument of type Moment is not assignable to parameter of type Date

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

export class JobExecution {
  public startTime: Moment;


  constructor() {
    this.stepExecutions = [];
  }

  public get startTimeFormatted(): string {
    return DateTimeUtils.formatAsDateTime(this.startTime);
  }
```

**It shows an error saying.**

> Argument of type 'Moment' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Date'.
>
> Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'Moment'.

```
return DateTimeUtils.formatAsDateTime(this.startTime)
```

This code is wrong

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Hi, when you has to show the source code or the messages, please put it in the body of the post, using the appropriate command of the editor, please: in this way, the people is more confortable to analyze the problem. Thank you

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

probably this will help

`return DateTimeUtils.formatAsDateTime(this.startTime.toDate());`

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Incomplete solution! When I use the solution.. I get DateTimeUtils not found.